# PHP display download link at email

Tags: php, html

This one is my code to display at email , my folder got 5 item , but it only display one link only , by right it should display 5 link

```
 $files = glob("../booking/file/".$id."/*.*");
        for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
        {
            $image = $files[$i];
            $supported_file = array('gif','jpg','jpeg','png', 'pdf');

            $d = $i + 1;
            $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
                $attch = '<a href="localhost/linxtravel/travelnew/travelnew/'.$image.'" target="_blank">('.$d.') Click here to download.</a><br/>';
                $checkattch = 1;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
```

Comment: _Note:_ you can remove the `else`-block from your `if`-statement. It's totally unnecessary and useless in that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [concatenate](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) the string using `.=` :

```
$attch .= '<a href="localhost/linxtravel/travelnew/travelnew/'.$image.'" target="_blank">('.$d.') Click here to download.</a><br/>';
```

Without, you overrides the variable `$attch` and you gets only the last link.

Answer (score 1):

In this place you always rewrite variable `$attch` each loop:

```
$attch = '<a href="localhost/linxtravel/travelnew/travelnew/'.$image.'" target="_blank">('.$d.') Click here to download.</a><br/>';
```

You need to append like this:

```
$attch. = '<a href="localhost/linxtravel/travelnew/travelnew/'.$image.'" target="_blank">('.$d.') Click here to download.</a><br/>';
```

And declarate variable before loop `for`:

```
$attch = '';
```